# IIS/CF10 index.cfm redirection with multiple port

Tags: iis-7, coldfusion

Got a strange problem..

I setup multiple websites on different ports in IIS 7.  I added each site and gave them each their own path.  I included CFIDE & Jakarta as virtual directories. When I hit localhost:8025 it supposed to go to C:\site1\index.cfm. However when I visit localhost:8025 it somehow jumps to C:\apps\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\index.cfm I do not have any websites setup that even goto c:\apps\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\
When I visit localhost:8025/something.cfm, then it pulls up just fine. It does some strange redirection only on index.cfm  I checked many configuration files and non of them include C:\apps\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\ as path for www

Any help would be appreciated. TIA